# What to do if your edit is rejected and you disagree?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

My [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19809606) was just rejected, and I don't agree with the reasoning for it.

> Nawrez reviewed this 28 mins ago: Reject
>   This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

How did my edit deviate from the original intent of the post? I replaced a link that has no information on it other than asking users to use another link (which is the one I wanted to insert in the answer instead).

But my question is what is the correct approach to "complain" about this other than posting on stack overflow meta?

Comment: IMO, you are changing the intent of the author, whom tried to use the arguably wrong term. The old link works, and someone still looking for "lettable" would have benefited from this answer (and from the link which both took you to the right place and informed you than the term was deprecated). Your edit obscured that information.

Comment: You can post a comment in the question with your suggestions.

Comment: @yivi The author uses the word "pipe" throughout his answer. Only in the end does he say "lettable" because the old link said lettable. IMO it makes the answer more confusing, and by replacing it with the correct term (as argued by the RxJs team) makes a great answer even more clear.  Going to the original link it says "We're calling them "pipeable operators", because no one knows what the heck "lettable" means.". So I removed the "lettable" from the answer which clearly has had a confusing meaning in the past

Comment: I still believe than the old link worked and provided more information than the edited version. I imagine that some point "lettable" was the proper word to use, and the answerer used that (and that link) around then. I think that an edit should preserve that information (e.g: _documentation on pipable (previously known as lettable)_) and the edit comment should make clear that the what happens with the link you are replacing. But that's just my opinion anyway, and I didn't review your edit in any case.

Comment: I did review the edit and it's basically what yivi says. The link still works, at the time of writing lettable was the correct term. If you edit it with something along what yivi suggested, I'm happy to approve it. I would have most probably used "improve edit" instead of reject if I would have read this meta post before the review.

Comment: The *"intention of the author"* was to link to the documentation that now lives on the *pipeable* page... If anything their intention is better preserved when the link is changed.

Comment: @BDL Why is it important to retain an inaccurate term in an answer? Sure if the author had used lettable all over his answer and it had some old syntax or something then I would not edit it. But that's not the case here. If someone reads the answer and does not click on the link then that person will maybe think that "lettable" is the correct term to use here. By changing it to pipeable the answer now uses the correct term and imo does not change the original intent of the answer at all

Comment: Does *anybody* ever agree about having his edit suggestion rejected?  The link is not actually bad, it both informs the reader that "lettable" is deprecated *and* links to the "good" article.  Give it another year or two.

Comment: It's not an incorrect term (imho). It's a term that was used by the project for some time and has changed in a more recent release. For me, the edit still looks as if someone is going through an answer updating it to a newer version of the library (which I don't think it's a good idea). At least the edit should have preserved the original term. I also would have accepted the edit if the original link had been dead. But it works and points to the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address your general question - if your edit was rejected and you disagree, there isn't much you can do.  You can try to propose it again if you strongly believe you are correct and hope the reviewers get it right this time, but don't keep trying because you are going to just end up annoying reviewers as you'll likely have the same reviewer more than once and they might end up flagging for a moderator.  Plus enough rejected edits in a short time frame might earn you a temporary edit ban.

The best course of action though is leaving a comment explaining the error and hope the author is still active and can make the change himself.  You could also try to find someone in chat who is experienced in the technology that can make the edit for you.

---

For this specific edit though, the reviewers who rejected the edit failed at their tasks because the rejection was flat out wrong.

Unfortunately the "this edit deviates from the authors intent" is over used anytime a change in code or links or anything happens that the reviewer thinks is radically changing the post.  This is a consequence of the fact that reviewers are not subject matter experts, so they may not  know what is correct and what is incorrect for a specific technology or language.

What the reviewers should have done is check the old link.  Had they done that, they would see the link points to a page that says:

> ### Stop trying to make "lettable" happen.
>
> :D
>
> We're calling them ["pipeable operators"](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md), because no one knows what the heck "lettable" means.

And the link is the link you were trying to point to.  I don't know RxJS at all, but had I seen that, I would have approved the edit.  And the reviewers should have done so too.

Comment: That's the exact same thing I did when I followed the link in the question but I refrained from acting on it since I found it via meta. We should indeed expect reviewers to follow links and check when edits like this are proposed.

Comment: As one of the reviewers who rejected: I have checked the link before rejecting, but found it important to keep the information that they were formally known as lettable operators in place. Simply stating that reviewers are wrong and didn't do their work properly is a bit offensive btw.

Comment: @BDL agreed, timing was funny but before reading your comment I saw the same thing.  I removed the word "wrong" because it was offensive.  But my opinion still stands that preserving the intent of the author isn't keeping a specific word or link, but linking to the appropriate page in the documentation as '@ivarni says, so the edit doesn't deviate at all from the authors intent